# How to configure AWS Step Function map input from codecommit file that contains a json array?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a step function that is attempting to pull a json array stored in a file from codecommit and put it into a map. That map is supposed to call a lambda function which prints the items in the json array. I'm currently getting an error that seems to imply the input to the map is a string literal instead of a json array. How do I correctly set it up so this array can be used as input to the map and each item is used for a lambda invocation?

I've tried converting the string using States.StringToJson and States.Array but have been unsuccessful. I've also tried different variations of specifying inputs and outputs without any luck.

The contents of the json file:

```
{"cars":["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"]}
```

The step function:

```
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "GetFile",
  "States": {
    "GetFile": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Next": "Map Cars",
      "Parameters": {
        "FilePath": "cars.json",
        "RepositoryName": "SampleRepo"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:codecommit:getFile",
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
          ],
          "Next": "Error Getting Config"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Error Getting Config": {
      "Type": "Fail",
      "Error": "Error Getting Config"
    },
    "Map Cars": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "InputPath": "$.FileContent",
      "ItemsPath": "$.cars",
      "ItemProcessor": {
        "ProcessorConfig": {
          "Mode": "DISTRIBUTED",
          "ExecutionType": "STANDARD"
        },
        "StartAt": "Lambda Invoke",
        "States": {
          "Lambda Invoke": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
            "Parameters": {
              "FunctionName": "printCar:$LATEST"
            },
            "End": true
          }
        }
      },
      "MaxConcurrency": 1000,
      "Label": "MapCars",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

The error:

```
{
  "error": "States.ReferencePathConflict",
  "cause": "Unable to apply step \"cars\" to input \"{\\\"cars\\\":[\\\"Ford\\\", \\\"BMW\\\", \\\"Fiat\\\"]}\""
}
```

MapStateEntered log:

```
{
  "name": "Map Cars",
  "input": "{\"BlobId\":\"xxxx\",\"CommitId\":\"xxxx\",\"FileContent\":\"{\\\"cars\\\":[\\\"Ford\\\", \\\"BMW\\\", \\\"Fiat\\\"]}\",\"FileMode\":\"NORMAL\",\"FilePath\":\"cars.json\",\"FileSize\":32}",
  "inputDetails": {
    "truncated": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Solved this by adding the following to GetFile: `"ResultSelector": {"carArray.$": "States.StringToJson($.FileContent)"}` and adding `"ItemsPath": "$.CarArray"` to Map Cars